# Comparing correlation between groups

Tags: regression, ancova

My data looks like this:

```
   year rainfall area species   density
1  1993   433.70   br      bs  8.9300000
2  1994   365.65   br      bs 39.1000000
3  1996   545.80   br      bs 21.2625213
4  1999   785.40   br      bs 32.1502058
5  2000   736.30   br      bs 44.0610606
6  2001   370.40   br      bs 16.0570919
7  2002   174.80   br      bs 29.2397661
8  2003   290.50   br      bs 37.5875495
9  2004   424.40   br      bs  6.1767797
10 2005   336.30   br      bs  5.3072410
11 2007   524.40   br      bs 18.8400000
12 2008   417.00   br      bs 27.5000000
```

(original png image: [kangaroodata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHegt.png) )

I have 5 species categories between which I want to compare the correlation of rainfall and density. I'm not exactly sure how to go about this and which tests to use. Looking around I've seen an ANCOVA suggested but which post-hoc test would I use to get pairwise comparison?

I've also seen someone work out all the individual regressions then do a chi squared but how would this work?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably plot the data and consider some sort of rank-based test using Spearman's $\rho$ or Kendall's $\tau$.  In this case it seems simply looking at the data is enough.  I personally don't see anything here, and wouldn't believe a statistical test that claims otherwise.

[image]

Comment: i've only included a small part of the data to show the format. I've run separate regressions on each of the 5 species and found significant results for all. 

I've been looking into it and it seems including an interaction between density and species category seems to be the way to go. would this be alright?

Comment: It's possible, but I would first look at the data to see what's happening.  Maybe the relationship is non-linear, so you wouldn't want to just blindly fit a linear model.  If you're fairly sure there is some kind of an association between rainfall and density, is the effect of species merely an additive shift, or does the nature of that association itself change?  If the latter is the case, then you could consider interactions.  But I would first try to get clues by examining the data visually.

Comment: so i've plotted the density vs rainfall for for each [species](http://i.imgur.com/Ko6SYa5.png). It doesn't look like a simple linear fit. where should i go from here? would log transformation work?

Comment: What exactly is the goal of the study?  You can tell by looking at these that there isn't much of a relationship except perhaps in the two rightmost plots.  It might be worth looking into what's happening between the rainfall values of 350 and 400 for "red" and "wally," though.  Instead of calculating some correlations, which I don't think would add much, I might just fit a robust regression line like a loess curve to emphasize some possible upward trends.  But I don't think a formal test or fancy model is going to indicate anything that isn't already fairly clear.

Comment: sorry i haven't been to clear before.

The study aims to look at the differences in the relationships between rainfall and population density between 5 species of kangaroos.

I'll look into the loess curves  however i was more concerned with the  statistical comparisons between any relationships i see