# Calculating differences of correlation between groups

Tags: r, regression, self-study, correlation

I don't know if I'm right here: I have a homework which where I have two supposedly correlating variables: Age of a crop and number of Larvae*; it looks like this:

```
Farmer Age_yrs Larvae_per_m²
1        Band       2          1315
2        Band       4           725
3        Band       6            90
4     Fechney       1           520
5     Fechney       3           285
6     Fechney       9            30
7  Mulholland       2           725
8  Mulholland       6            20
```

(...)

I suppose I have to look if the correlation between Age and Larvae (which I found to be positive) are not influenced by another variable.

So I guess I have to find out if the correlations are significantly different among the groups?

But I'm not even sure if such a thing is possible because the groups consist partially merely of two variables...

This is probably similar: [Comparing correlation between groups](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162746/comparing-correlation-between-groups) but I haven't found an answer in this.

**Any statistician who knows what to do here? Thanks!**

**4. The larvae of weevils are a pest in alfalfa. It was, however, hypothesized that weevil populations decline as the alfalfa stand gets older and you are asked to assess this statistically.  You  receive  data  from  different  farms  that  differ  inter  alia  in  their  pest management strategies. Can you find the hypothesized relationship? Plot your results appropriately.*

Comment: Look into [mixed-effects models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model).

Comment: Calling your dataset `d`, try this: `names(d) = c('Farmer', 'Age', 'Larvae'); attach(d); library(lme4); library(lmerTest); fit = lmer(Larvae ~ Age + (1|Farmer)); summary(fit); anova(fit); rand(fit)`.